# Xcode (Swift) Documentation says to set property to YES, but only works when set to true?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, boolean

I am working with AVAudioPlayer in Swift. It inherits from NSObject. On the documentation for "enableRate" under the AVAudioPlayer it states:

"To enable adjustable playback rate for an audio player, set this property to YES after you initialize the player..."

When actually implementing this in Xcode, it works only if I set

```
audioPlayer.enableRate = true
```

Is the "YES" written in the documentation referring to using "true", or it is something inherited from Objective C?

Thank you.

Comment: on the apple documentation links at the upper right bar of the page there is a toggle button which switches documentation between Swift and Objective-C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In objective-C, booleans could be true/YES or false/NO. However, in swift it is only true or false, so in this case a YES would correspond to true and a NO would correspond to false when translating from objective-C to swift.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, booleans have the value YES or NO. In Swift, they have the value true or false.